# Differences between BaseHttpServer and wsgiref.simple_server

Tags: python, basehttpserver, wsgiref

I'm looking for a module that provides me a basic http server capabilities for local access. It seems like Python has two methods to implement simple http servers in the standard library: [wsgiref.simple_server](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server) and [BaseHttpServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html).

What are the differences? Is there any strong reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer:** `wsgiref.simple_server` is a WSGI adapter over `BaseHTTPServer`.

**Longer answer:**

`BaseHTTPServer` (and [`SocketServer`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html), on which it builds) is the module that implements most of the actual HTTP server. It can accept requests and return responses, but it has to know how to handle those requests. When you are using `BaseHTTPServer` directly, you provide the handlers by subclassing [`BaseHTTPRequestHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler), for example:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('Hello world!\n')

HTTPServer(('', 8000), MyHandler).serve_forever()
```

`wsgiref.simple_server` adapts this `BaseHTTPServer` interface to the [WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) specification, which is the standard for server-independent Python web applications. In WSGI, you provide the handler in the form of a function, for example:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def my_app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    yield 'Hello world!\n'

make_server('', 8000, my_app).serve_forever()
```

The `make_server` function returns an instance of [`WSGIServer`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.simple_server.WSGIServer), which inherits most of the actual protocol/network logic from [`BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer) and [`SocketServer.TCPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.TCPServer) (although it does end up reimplementing some simple rules of HTTP). What mainly differs is the way you integrate your application code with that logic.

It really depends on the problem you’re trying to solve, but coding against `wsgiref` is probably a better idea because it will make it easy for you to move to a different, production-grade HTTP server, such as [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), in the future.